# Dynamically update "Comparator" on-the-fly for Java PriorityBlockingQueue

Tags: java

I am using java PriorityBlockingQueue for queuing processing items. In my code, I will build a Comparator instance (with some predefined criteria), then pass it as a parameter when constructing PriorityBlockingQueue.

```
new PriorityBlockingQueue(10000, Comparator.comparing(...))
```

Now, a requirement is that the system maintainer would need to update sorting criteria on-the-fly for the PriorityBlockingQueue. (e.g by calling a exposed REST API or modify specific config), such that those processing items could be sorted by the latest criteria.

My question is that, is there anyway to modify the "Comparator" within a PriorityBlockingQueue?

Comment: Just copy it to a new queue

Comment: The queue will already have been sorted so if you'd change the comparator you'd it up. As shmosel suggested you might want to create a new queue and copy the old one's contents.

Comment: No, there is no way you can modify the comparator after creating the queue. At least only a hack that, as Thomas said, will create havoc in your program. You don’t want that. Do what shmosel said.

Comment: Just a rough thought, can we build a customized class that implements Comparator interface?  Thus we can put those dynamic logic into compare() method.

Comment: You can, and it will be sure to f\*ck up. You don’t want that. The queue will not sort the elements again when the behaviour of the `compare` method changes dynamically. So you won’t know what you get, and the queue may even throw exceptions when the `compare` method doesn’t behave consistently. (If you really insist, you can take out all the elements, change the sorting behaviour and fill the elements back in. It *may* work, no guarantees. And I will certainly consider it a hack.)

Comment: Indeed, I've done quite a lot of searching from internet, there are some of post saying "not suggest to change comparator on-the-fly". However, after I wrote some test codes to verify, I found "having dynamic code in compare() method" seem working fine. So, I really curious is what kind of certain situation will not work?